# Why is calculating the volume of the Birkhoff polytope complicated?

Tags: geometry, volume, polytopes, discrete-geometry, birkhoff-polytopes

It is known that calculating the volume of the [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope) in higher dimension is still open.

I am not very good at it. I am trying to understand  why it is complicated. It would be really great if someone could explain it easily. Any link or reference will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A better question might be 'why would you expect it to be easy'?  The _best_ deterministic polytope-volume algorithms we have in arbitrary dimensions scale as high powers of the number of vertices (last I checked it was something like $O(v^{10})$ or something on that order) and here the number of vertices is super-exponential in the dimension. Computing the volume of an arbitrary-dimension shape is much, *much* harder than computing the volume of a plane or space figure.